# Python - copy only today photos from the folder

Tags: python

i want copy only today photos from the folder :\myshare\all_folders
to \myshare\new\all_new_photos

if (date modified = today date )copy the photo

```
import os
from shutil import copy
dir_src = r"\\myshare\all_folders"
dir_dst = r"\\myshare\new\all_new_photos"



for root, _, files in os.walk(dir_src):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.jpg'):
            copy(os.path.join(root, file), dir_dst)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `os.path.getmtime`:

```
import os
import datetime, os
from shutil import copy
dir_src = r"\\myshare\all_folders"
dir_dst = r"\\myshare\new\all_new_photos"
for root, _, files in os.walk(dir_src):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.jpg') and (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, file))).date() == datetime.datetime.now().date()):
            copy(os.path.join(root, file), dir_dst)
```

Comment: please write all code with dir_src

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @MosaabAhmad Edited my answer now it should work